# Rate of decreasing sleeping time question

Tags: improper-integrals

can someone help me solve this problem?

It is estimated that $t$-weeks into a semester, the average amount of sleep a college math student gets per day $S(t)$ decreases at a rate of $$\frac{-6t}{e^{t^2}}$$ hours per day. When the semester begins, math students sleep an average of 8 hours per day. What is $S(t)$, 8 week(s) into the semester?

Sorry, the equation is a bit weird, but please ignore that bracket.

I got until the point where 8 + the integral of it = unknown, and used substitution where I made  $$u=e^{t^2}$$
and solved it to get:
$$8+\frac{3}{u}$$ with 8 and 0 for coefficients. I tried solving it but the answer was not right. Can someone find my mistake?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you please include all your work? Other people might give you an alternative solution, but it is hard to see where your mistake is from your work so far.

Answer (score 2):

I assume these are the steps you have followed.

Substitute $u = e^{t^2}$, $du = 2t e^{t^2} dt$ to get:

$$\int \frac{-6t}{e^{t^2}} \mathrm d t$$
$$=\int\frac{-6t}{u} \frac{du}{2t e^{t^2}} $$
$$= \int \frac{-3}{e^{t^2}} \frac{du}{u}$$
$$= -3 \int \frac{1}{u} \frac{du}{u}$$
$$= -3 \left(\frac{u^{-1}}{-1} \right) + C$$

Now the first problem: you have to substitute $u$ back in,

$$S(t) = 3e^{-t^2} + C$$

and the second problem is: $C$ is not $8$. To see why, substitute $t = 0$ into that last equation to find what $C$ is.

You should be able to continue.

Comment: Don't forget you can [accept](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) answers by clicking the green tick.